# How do I get the value of offset to be between 0 and 232?

Tags: vuforia

I am trying to upload an `.obj` file to Vuforia MTG and keep getting this error:

> Error: Invalid Model
> RangeError: The value of "offset" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 232. Received 236

I got the `.obj` from PhotoCatch.
 I thought I went through the normal photogrammetry process (with depth & proportional scale) - cropping the object, etc.

I have tried adjusting the coordinates of the object (i.e. x, y, z) and reducing the quality of the object (in PhotoCatch) and keep getting an offset of 236.

Comment: It is not clear what this offset might refer to. However, does the obj load ok on other tools like Meshlab (www.meshlab.net) or Blender? Also, you might want to try to convert your obj to a different format like gltf and then try to pass the converted file to MTG.

Comment: @emay the file does not work in meshlab. I'm not sure what the issue is - but the issue appears to be in my .obj file.